# ¿Como debo transformar una serie que esta en minutos a horas para realizar mi scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con dos series en `Pandas`. **Radiación** con datos cada minuto y **Humedad** con datos cada hora. Necesito hallar la forma de hacer los ciclos anuales y luego realizar un scatterplot, para ello necesito que mis dos series tengan la misma cantidad de datos y que sea cada hora. Mis datos de **Radiación** están cada minuto.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import scipy.stats

Data = np.genfromtxt('6001_Pira_1.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',')

Fecha_Hora = Data[:,1]
Radiacion = Data[:,2].astype(np.float)
Temperatura = Data[:,3].astype(np.float)
Calidad = Data[:,4].astype(np.float)

Radiacion_Filtrado = Radiacion[(Calidad == 1) | (Calidad == 2)]
Fecha_Hora_Filtrada = Fecha_Hora[(Calidad == 1) | (Calidad == 2)]

FechaHora_1 = []
for i in range(len(Fecha_Hora_Filtrada)):
tmp  = Fecha_Hora_Filtrada[i] 
Date = datetime.strptime(tmp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - timedelta(hours=5)
FechaHora_1.append(Date)


Radiacion_Proyecto = pd.DataFrame(Radiacion_Filtrado,FechaHora_1)

Radiacion_Proyecto = Radiacion_Proyecto['2016-03':]

#Ciclos diurnos 

Serie = Radiacion_Proyecto

Median  = []
Mean    = []
perc25  = []
perc_75 = []
perc_10 = []
perc_90 = []

for i in range(24):

**# Si fuera Ciclo Anual
# Data['2015-' + np.str(i)] # La i son los 12 meses (Contador)
#print i** 

a = Serie.between_time(np.str(i)+':00', np.str(i)+':59')
a = a.values[np.isfinite(a.values)]
Median.append(np.median(a))
Mean.append(np.mean(a))
perc25.append(np.percentile(a,25))
perc_75.append(np.percentile(a,75))
perc_10.append(np.percentile(a,10))
perc_90.append(np.percentile(a,90)) 

**#Ciclo anual
# Si fuera Ciclo Anual
#for i in range(12): 
FP = Serie(['2016 -' + np.str(i)])
#a = Serie.between_time(np.str(i)+':00', np.str(i)+':59')
# La i son los 12 meses (Contador)
#print i** **No se como hacerlo!**
```

## ____________________________________________________________________________________________

```
 Data_Humedad = np.genfromtxt('Datos107_1H.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',' )

 Fechahora_Humedad = Data_Humedad[: , 0]
 H2 = Data_Humedad[:, 1]


 Humedad = []
 Fecha_Hum = []
 for i in range(len(H2)):
 try:
    Humedad.append(np.float(H2[i]))
    Fecha_Hum.append(Fechahora_Humedad[i])
 except:
    pass

 Humedad = np.array(Humedad)
 Fecha_Hum = np.array(Fecha_Hum)

 FechaHora_H = []
 for i in range(len(Fecha_Hum)):
 H  = Fecha_Hum[i] 
 Date = datetime.strptime(H, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
 FechaHora_H.append(Date)


 Humedad_Proyecto = pd.DataFrame(Humedad, FechaHora_H)
 Humedad_Proyecto = Humedad_Proyecto["2016-03":]


 #Ciclos diurnos 

 Serie1 = Humedad_Proyecto

 MedianH  = []
 MeanH   = []
 perc25H  = []
 perc_75H = []
 perc_10H = []
 perc_90H = []

 for i in range(24):
 # Si fuera Ciclo Anual
 # Data['2015-' + np.str(i)] # La i son los 12 meses (Contador)
 #print i 
 b = Serie1.between_time(np.str(i)+':00', np.str(i)+':00')
 b = b.values[np.isfinite(b.values)]
 MedianH.append(np.median(b))
 MeanH.append(np.mean(b))
 perc25H.append(np.percentile(b,25))
 perc_75H.append(np.percentile(b,75))
 perc_10H.append(np.percentile(b,10))
 perc_90H.append(np.percentile(b,90))
```

## ________________________________________________________________________

```
 # Las series deben tener la misma cantidad de registros
 # Recortamos las series al máximo registro posible
 Humedad_ProyectoR  = Humedad_Proyecto['2016-03':'2016-11']
 Radiacion_ProyectoR    = Radiacion_Proyecto['2016-03':'2016-11']

 Humedad_ProyectoR  = Humedad_Proyecto['2012-03':'2016-11']

2016-03-01 00:00:00  60.211667
2016-03-01 01:00:00  60.880000
2016-03-01 02:00:00  60.496667
2016-03-01 03:00:00  60.733333
2016-03-01 04:00:00  60.455000
2016-03-01 05:00:00  60.011667
2016-03-01 06:00:00  60.675000
2016-03-01 07:00:00  60.638333
2016-03-01 08:00:00  60.790000
2016-03-01 09:00:00  60.018333
2016-03-01 10:00:00  60.021667
2016-03-01 11:00:00  60.165000
2016-03-01 12:00:00  60.568333
2016-03-01 13:00:00  61.191525
2016-03-01 14:00:00  60.666667
2016-03-01 15:00:00  59.481667
2016-03-01 16:00:00  60.790000
2016-03-01 17:00:00  60.156667
2016-11-29 23:00:00  41.416667
2016-11-30 00:00:00  41.348718
2016-11-30 01:00:00  41.324528
2016-11-30 06:00:00  41.115789
2016-11-30 07:00:00  41.098333
2016-11-30 08:00:00  41.009375
2016-11-30 09:00:00  40.831250
2016-11-30 10:00:00  40.660465
2016-11-30 11:00:00  40.451111
2016-11-30 12:00:00  40.275000
2016-11-30 13:00:00  40.130357
2016-11-30 14:00:00  40.035000
2016-11-30 15:00:00  40.003226
2016-11-30 16:00:00  39.950000
2016-11-30 17:00:00  39.964815
2016-11-30 18:00:00  39.960000
2016-11-30 19:00:00  39.918868
2016-11-30 20:00:00  39.900000
2016-11-30 21:00:00  39.887500
2016-11-30 22:00:00  39.882456
2016-11-30 23:00:00  39.883051

[5521 rows x 1 columns]
```

.

```
Radiacion_ProyectoR = Radiacion_Proyecto['2012-03':'2016-11']

2016-03-09 00:01:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:02:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:03:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:04:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:05:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:06:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:07:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:08:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:09:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:10:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:11:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:12:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:13:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:14:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:15:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:16:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:17:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:18:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:19:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:20:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:21:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:22:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:23:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:24:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:25:00   -2
2016-03-09 00:26:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:27:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:28:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:29:00   -1
2016-03-09 00:30:00   -1
...                  ...
2016-11-09 16:24:00  103
2016-11-09 16:25:00  105
2016-11-09 16:26:00  108
2016-11-09 16:27:00  110
2016-11-09 16:28:00  114
2016-11-09 16:29:00  117
2016-11-09 16:30:00  120
2016-11-09 16:31:00  121
2016-11-09 16:32:00  121
2016-11-09 16:33:00  120
2016-11-09 16:34:00  120
2016-11-09 16:35:00  118
2016-11-09 16:36:00  116
2016-11-09 16:37:00  114
2016-11-09 16:38:00  113
2016-11-09 16:39:00  112
2016-11-09 16:40:00  112
2016-11-09 16:41:00  113
2016-11-09 16:42:00  114
2016-11-09 16:43:00  116
2016-11-09 16:44:00  117
2016-11-09 16:45:00  117
2016-11-09 16:46:00  121
2016-11-09 16:47:00  131
2016-11-09 16:48:00  140
2016-11-09 16:49:00  148
2016-11-09 16:50:00  158
2016-11-09 16:51:00  164
2016-11-09 16:52:00  166
2016-11-09 16:53:00  162

[316305 rows x 1 columns]
```

Para pasar la serie de cada minuto a cada hora hago:

```
Radiacion_PHoras = Radiacion_ProyectoR.resample("1H", label="right").mean()
```

Pero solo me devuelve un dato:

```
Radiacion_PHoras
0    218.198817
dtype: float64
```

Además al hacer reindex todos mis datos se convierten en `NaN`

```
Radiacion_Final = Radiacion_PHoras.reindex(pd.date_range('2016-03-02 00:00','2016-11-08 00:00', freq='1H'))
```

¿Qué debo hacer? Me es necesario tener las dos series con la misma cantidad de datos.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Pandas verdad?, deberias especificar con que librería trabajas e indicarlo como etiqueta. Además tampoco vendría mal una muestra de los datos y de la estructura de tabulación para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample)

Tomando como ejemplo este fragmento de tu `dataframe`

```
                    valor
fecha   
2016-03-09 00:01:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:02:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:03:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:04:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:05:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:06:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:07:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:08:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:09:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:10:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:11:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:12:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:13:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:14:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:15:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:16:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:17:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:18:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:19:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:20:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:21:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:22:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:23:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:24:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:25:00 -2
2016-03-09 00:26:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:27:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:28:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:29:00 -1
2016-03-09 00:30:00 -1
```

Vamos a obtener el promedio cada 10 minutos (Como no tengo todos los datos lo hice con 10 min, tendrías que modificarlo en tu programa)

```
df1 = df.resample('10Min').mean()
```

Al imprimir `df1` obtenemos

```
                    valor
fecha   
2016-03-09 00:00:00 -1.0
2016-03-09 00:10:00 -1.4
2016-03-09 00:20:00 -1.6
2016-03-09 00:30:00 -1.0
```

Para que esto funcione de forma correcta es necesario que el índice sea de tipo DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex, o TimedeltaIndex

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', index_col='fecha')
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1 = df.resample('10Min').mean()
print(df1)
```